# Adding numbers to the theorem in Beamer

Tags: beamer, overleaf

How can I add numbers to the theorems in beamer like Theorem 0.1 or 1.1? When I tried I just got Theorem 1 instead of  Theorem 0.1, please help me.

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please provide a full [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) which reproduces the issue, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}

Answer (score 1):

This shows how to number `theorem` within `section`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\counterwithin{theorem}{section}

\begin{document}
\section{title}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{theorem}
    content
  \end{theorem}
  \begin{theorem}
    content
  \end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{theorem}
    content
  \end{theorem}
  \begin{theorem}
    content
  \end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]